# localhost in WAMP not working

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

i use WAMP 2.2. installed and the ison is green.
problem is the , when I enter locahost in URL , it doesn't work
but when I enter 127.0.0.1 it works.

what is the reason ?

Comment: I use easyphp and they are stating "Due to incompatibilities with Windows Vista/Seven, 'localhost' is no longer used. Use '127.0.0.1' instead." Most likely it is the same issue.

Comment: Try adding **127.0.0.1 localhost** to your C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts file

Comment: which browser do you use? and what happens when you open the tray-menu and click at "localhost"?

Comment: same effect when open using the icon tray "localhost". It give same error msg : Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: yes, the  127.0.0.1 localhost already available in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMZT5AmYl1M) was the third entry when I googled "wamp Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"

Comment: try changing `locahost ` to `localhost `?..

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that either:

A. Your Windows Hosts file does not have this entry:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

B. Or this entry is 1st (comes before the above), and Apache is Listening on IPv4 only:

```
::1 localhost
```

In the second case, just remove or comment out the entry.

Hosts file path:

```
C:Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

You'll need to edit Hosts file via 'Run as admin' on Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using windows 8.
Please follow this guide to fix your wamp in Windows 8

[How to run WAMP Server on Windows 8](http://graftalks.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/how-to-use-wamp-server-on-windows-8.html)

Downgrading to Windows 7 is not a bad option if you are a regular developer.