# wampserver does not accede to my local website despite the fact that all services are active

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, wampserver

my operating system is windows 7 ( SP1 )
i tried both 2.5 and 3 versions of wampserver (installed as admin)
 in spite of the fact that all services are actives ,
the server fails to accede/refer files located under www and i get an error related to DNS !!!!! 
i heard about virtual host but i want to know should i make a new vhost for every local project ( i'm just trying to learn php not to make real sites ) ? 
( i have a friend who has the same versions as me , he is making folders under www and it works quietly ! ) 
Besides my file " hosts" of windows contains this " # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

## 127.0.0.1       localhost

## ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost   "

Comment: [WAMPServer Troubleshooting tips](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915) and [All you need to know about WAMPServer 3](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295) and most important [The need for Virtual Hosts](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [localhost in WAMP not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097396/localhost-in-wamp-not-working)